# populate an array with jQuery.children()?

Tags: jquery, arrays

simple question mainly for simplifying purposes but...

currently using

```
var categoryList = [];
$('#share').children().each(function() {
    categoryList.push($(this).html());
});
```

I was curious if there was a way to just populate the array in 1 go... I realize that the .children() does return an array, but I guess the complexity comes from the fact that I need the .html or .text of each child (either would suffice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the combined HTML of all the children, you can either just do this to get the HTML for the whole object:

```
var html = $('#share').html();
```

or this to get the concatenated HTML of all the children (without their individual tags):

```
var html = $('#share').children().map(function() {return $(this).html()}).get().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe .makeArray(obj) might help?

in your case:

```
var categoryList = $.makeArray($('#share'));
```

but then you might have to still traverse each item within the array to get the HTML from the contained elements, but i guess you can do that later when you need to use the elements..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Answer (score 0):

one thing that you can do is to use this simple solution:

```
categoryList = $('#share > *');
```

and play with the array in this way:

```
categoryList[0].innerHTML
```

when you need it, I think it's faster and easier.